# How to edit wordpress files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I have installed WordPress on my localhost and even installed and activated a new theme. Now, I want to add horizontal navigation to my wordpress, but I have no idea how to do that or which particular file I need to edit. Can anyone help me whit that or suggest any tutorial that has step by step instructions to learn word press..?

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: see this documents -->> http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Horizontal_Menus

Comment: And this will help you also -->> with file name which you need to update -->> http://wordpress.org/support/topic/kubrick-need-a-page-navigation-bar?replies=23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which theme you are using, in my case I refer to the default TwentyThirteen WordPress theme. Open up the folder WP is installed in and navigate to the header.php file in the path as follows:

```
your-wordpress-site/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/header.php
```

In that file you can edit the navbar starting at this line:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbarShadow">
```

You must also find the style.css file and edit that for CSS.

Comment: Is there any trick that can help to locate a particular file?

Comment: Which file are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the documentation
http://codex.wordpress.org/